# What is the information wasted for a 2-3 node of a tree?

Tags: java

Assume I have a node class for a 2-3 tree. Every node can store 2 data elements and at most 3 children. If there is one node in the tree store 1 data element and have no children. what is the storage wasted for this node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the data you want to store in the tree.
Let's assume you want to store an object, string or some other complex data type in the tree. Then you have 2 pointers (one for ever object) and 3 pointers for the children. The node needs the space even though the pointer are not initialized/point to `null`. So you have a memory usage of 1/5.

Example:

Image you have the following class:

```
class Node {
    Object data1 = new Data();
    Object data2 = null;
    Node child1 = null;
    Node child2 = null;
    Node child3 = null;
}
```

When you create an object of this class the VM needs to reserve memory for the new object. So the VM knows that there are 5 different attributes in this class. Each attribute is a Object, so there needs to be space for 5 pointers. Where the pointer is actually pointing to doesn't matter because it is just the value that stands in the pointer. A `null` pointer is just a pointer that points to a invalid address (for example `0x00000000`, but this depends on the operating system).

So the memory for storing `data1` and `data2` are exactly the same. Of course `data1` points to a valid address and there is an other object that also needs memory.

So what happens exactly, when the object is created?
Let's assume the object is created on the stack (on the heap it would be exactly the same). The VM 'pushes' each attribute after each other on the stack. I am not sure about the exact order, but I would assume it is `data1, data2, child1,...`, from top to bottom. In this case 5 times 32bit or 64bit (depends on your architecture) are reserved. I'll just call them *word*, I can't remember the correct expression for it. The value of each word is now a random value (the value that was stored in these memory cells). Next for each word the correct values are added, so for `null` `0x00000000` is written in the memory cells. For `data1` a free address is searched and there it starts all over again.

I hope it is clear what I am trying to say.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on this? I am actually interested, I've never thought about it and don't remember seeing it referenced in any of the documentation I've read.

Comment: What do you mean with documentation? I have nothing for a 2-3 tree (didn't even know such a thing exists :P), it is more like how objects in general are stored in the memory (espacially on the stack).

Comment: @zgc7009 I can edit my post to add are more detailed description (including an example) if you are interessted in it.

Comment: Documentation that says that if you set a node to null that it allocates space for the contents contained within the node. Where did you learn that from? If you have a 2-3 tree with 1 item in the parent node and set the 3 children to null I thought it would have like 50% space efficiency.

Comment: So, the space efficiency would be 50% or 20%?

Comment: @Ennosigaeon sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: @zgc7009 I edited my comment, when it is not clear just let me know

Comment: @Ennosigaeon Been a long day :P Wasn't thinking about having to still reference a Node object even though it is null. Brain fart